# Looking for feedback from people that have gone from 100% web development to winforms

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I have been a web developer for my entire development career. Nearly 100% microsoft focused the entire time. I have been using .Net, both C# and VB.Net, since beta. I now find myself in a position to where I have the opportunity to start doing some WinForms development in C# using the 3.5 framework. As with anything new, I am excited about the learning opportunity in front of me.

I am curious if anyone has any suggested books, articles, feedback, etc on the topic of transitioning from web development to winforms in the .Net world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it goes without saying that the paradigms are very different.  I really enjoy C# because of how easy it is to write great windows software.

Start by getting into the IDE and creating a real but small project.  One of my first C# projects was a light weight budget program.  That took me into many areas of C#, from XML handling to custom windows controls, to debugging, and more.

Experience is the best teacher.  Take time to look at the function lists, and peruse the documentation.  Get a feel for what is in the thousands of classes that make up .NET.

Reading books can be nice, but getting your hands dirty (in conjunction with a good book) is far more effective.

Set a goal and go for it, you will have no problem learning all about it.  Don't be afraid to try things and take risks -- it helps you learn the system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are moving from Web to Windows, there is a some significant differences between the two enviroments. Some good and some are bad. If your .Net based and moving to 3.5 look into WPF since it is the best of both worlds for Web developers converting right now.

I do know of some common mistakes made by web developers making the crossover. They would include:

- Opening database connections on every form and every database calls. (In Windows Bad)
- There is no ViewState concept or Stateless concept in Windows

I am sure there is a few more that can be added but right now I can't think of an exact list.

I do agree with gahooa, look at doing a small project and read as much as possible on the subject. Approach it as if you never developed before, and the skills you gained over the years will automatically kick in when needed.